# fill other text inputs with MySQL values based on select box option

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this select box that populates from MySQL Data using PHP

```
<select>
    <?php
    $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from prices ");
    $stmt->execute(array());
    $records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($records as $result2) {
        echo '<option value="'.$result2["product"].'">'.$result2["product"].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

in the same table in MySQL (prices) there is a retail column, how can i put the value of retail into a text input

```
<input type="text" name="unitprice" />
```

based on the selected row in the select box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using JavaScript.

**Option 1**

I would convert your results into a JSON Array and echo it to JavaScript. This way all information gets given the user.

```
<select id="mySelectBox" onchange="changeValue(this.value);">
<?php
$json_array = array();
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from prices ");
$stmt->execute(array());
$records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($records as $result2) {
    $product = $result2["product"];
    $json_array[$product] = $result2['unitprice'];
    echo '<option value="'.$result2["product"].'">'.$result2["product"].'</option>';
}
json_encode($json_array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
</select>
<input type="text" id="unitPrice" name="unitprice" />


<script>
var json = <?php echo $json_array; ?>;
function changeValue(myValue) {
    document.getElementById("unitPrice").value = json[myValue];
}


</script>
```

Comment: i want the retail value for the selected item to automatically be added into the unit price text input

Comment: As I said, I'll be editing this. As you see now, there's javascript that SHOULD update the unit price text input. Seems like you've got quite a bit to learn :P I'd recommend looking up about what json is so you understand this code. Much better than just copying & pasting :)

Comment: i will be learning this a bit more however i needed this one done quickly :) - it doesn't seem to be updating the unit price text input

Comment: Just made an edit to the select onchange="selectChanged();" - I currently don't have a way to test this. About to use jsfiddle and a written js array. Just spotted another error too! Sorry about that.

Comment: Be sure to understand what's happening. json_encode takes a PHP array and turns it into a JSON Object, similar to an array. This JSON Object can be read by JavaScript and many other languages can take a JSON Object and decode it into that languages version of objects/arrays. For example in PHP, you can do json_decode($json_array); and then you will be able to access the array as normal in PHP again. Once it's given the javascript, we access the object when the drop down menu changes.

Comment: still showing as undefined when i choose an option :(

Comment: Did you update this line? <select id="mySelectBox" onchange="changeValue(this.value);">

Comment: my table column (retail) is a FLOAT

Comment: That shouldn't matter. :/

Comment: Try doing json_encode($json_array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);